# How to extract sample values from an imported WAV file?

Tags: import, sound

Suppose I read a file with

```
B = Import["something.wav"]
```

Now how can I obtain a list of sample values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want this:

```
data = Import["test.wav", "Data"]
```

This imports the raw data of sample values. For example, on a test file of approximately 10 seconds, stereo at 48000 Hz, data is an array of size 2 × 520192 (from which I can deduce that my recording was actually 10.84 seconds).

See the [documentation for WAV format import/export](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/WAV.html), as well as [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3286/700) on a related question for some more details.

---

Going at it differently, if you already have imported your file as a [`Sound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sound.html) object (as in your example), you can still recover the sample data. Inside your `Sound` object is a [`SampledSoundList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampledSoundList.html):

```
In[25]:= Head@First@B
Out[25]= SampledSoundList
```

This in turn contains the raw data:

```
In[26]:= Length@B[[1, 1]]
Out[26]= 2

In[27]:= Table[Length@B[[1, 1, i]], {i, 1, 2}]
Out[27]= {520192, 520192}
```