# How to import sound file from computer?

Tags: import, sound

I know you can import sounds/images from the Mathematica library, but I was wondering if I could import sounds I have on my computer (i.e. .wav files)? I've tried using the Import functon and properly named the file, but it says it can't be found. Thank you for any assistance anyone can provide!

Comment: Did you provide the full path to your file?

Comment: It is possible to import .wav files. Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/WAV.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're telling Mathematica to look the right place:

```
SetDirectory["/Users/me/Desktop/sound-files"]
```

> /Users/me/Desktop/sound-files

List the files:

```
FileNames["*.wav"]
```

> {"asteroidexplode.wav", "fire.wav", "rule30.wav", "shipexplode.wav", 
>   "thrust.wav"}

Then import a file:

```
fire = Import["fire.wav"]
```

[image: screen grab]

Now you can refer to the [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/how-to-extract-sample-values-from-an-imported-wav-file) that @Yves pointed to in the comments.