# Methods offered by SeedRandom

Tags: random

Regarding on the Mathematica documentation, `SeedRandom` offers several methods, which are distingushable in terms of degree of randomness I guess. Does anybody have a good idea, how to find the best method, when `RandomReal` should be used in order to get a set of bestly-uncorrelated values in a 100 x 100 Matrix like this:

```
RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}]
```

Comment: Strange, before posting, my first search did not reveal this comprehensive Investigation: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/quality-of-random-numbers?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

- I don't think "degree of randomness" is a well-defined term. The different random number generators differ in which tests for randomness the do well on and which they do not do well on. There is no way to order them by "degree of randomness".
- You don't change the way you call `RandomReal` and related functions to change the random number generator. You change the generator by making a call to `SeedRandom` and giving it a `Method` option.

#### References

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html
- [What pseudo-random number generators are available to Mathematica users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95533/)